# Limit 3g bandwidth usage with raspberry + mqtt

Tags: networking

My setup is a simple raspberry with a 3g dongle shooting mqtt messages to a remote server.

Each message takes less than 50bytes, messages are sent every 10 min which gives a daily network usage of 7kB. Now my provider charges me around 500kB per day.

Any guess for these 2 orders of magnitude?

Comment: Its a maths question. Maybe it can be answered on Maths Q&A if somebody is looking for an upvote or two.

Comment: @ppumkin `50kB` should read `50bytes`, simple math =)

Comment: Skim error + I didn't get the question but now I do. Still think its off topic. But like @user12668 answered, it may be  a provider policy. They might charge him in blocks of 500kb - Because even if they rounded to the kb it doesn't make sense :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pi will need to connect send your data then disconnect from the network on each cycle or you will be charged.
Ask your provider for a network breakdown of connection and you may find some interesting activity
Kenny